# Как получить параметр из дочернего фрагмента в родительский при нажатии назад?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть 2 фрагмента 1 фрагмент запускает 2 через navigate. При нажатии назад 2 фрагмента мне надо передать параметр в 1 фрагмент. А в 1 фрагменте отследить закрытие этого фрагмента и получить параметр от 2 фрагмента

Comment: Переопределите, .OnBackPressed() и отправляйте bundle с инфой через .navigate()

Comment: [Fragment Result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылку, вы меня спасли, сейчас попробую.